Connectedness and Path-Connectedness of Subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with exactly one irrational coordinate.
Consider the set $S\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ of all points which have exactly one irrational coordinate. That is $$x=(x_1,x_2)\in S \iff x_1 \text{ or } x_2 \text{ irrational but not both irrational}$$
Is $S$ connected? Is $S$ path-connected?

My Attempt
I claim that the set $S$ is connected. Suppose there exists $U,V$ open in $S$ and non-empty such that $U\cup V=S$ and $U\cap V = \emptyset$. Then by definition of the subspace topology, $\exists \tilde{U},\tilde{V}$ open sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $U=\tilde{U}\cap S$ and $V=\tilde{V}\cap S$. Since $S$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\tilde{U}\cup \tilde{V}=\mathbb{R}^2$. Since both $\tilde{U}$ and $\tilde{V}$ are open and $\mathbb{R}^2$ is connected, $\tilde{U}\cap \tilde{V}\neq \emptyset$ and moreover this intersection is an open set. Fix any $x\in \tilde{U}\cap \tilde{V}$, then as the intersection is open, $\exists \varepsilon>0$ such that $B_{\varepsilon}(x)\subset \tilde{U}\cap \tilde{V}$. This ball will contain some point $(i,q)$ where $i$ is irrational and $q$ is rational by a density argument. But then this is a point in $U\cap V$, a contradiction to it being empty. Whence, $S$ is connected.
I am having more trouble showing whether $S$ is path-connected. I am really not sure where to start with this. I cannot think of how to explicitly construct a path between two points. On the other hand, I'm not sure how to disprove path-connectedness. I had thought of showing there is no continuous way to leave a given point in $S$ whilst still staying in $S$ but did not get very far. To do this, I fixed the points $a=(\sqrt{2},1)$ and $b=(1,\sqrt{2})$. I then supposed there was some path $\gamma:[0,1]\to S$ which connected these points. I defined the first leaving 'time' of the path from $a$ as $$t_0=\inf\{t:\gamma(t)\neq a\}$$ Then, since $\gamma$ is continuous, and so are the projection maps $\pi_X$ and $\pi_Y$, $\gamma(t_0)=a$. Then by definition of the infemum, for any $\delta>0$ there exists $t_1$ such that $t_0<t_1<t_1+\delta$ with $\gamma(t_1)\neq a$. Then, as $[t_0,t_1]$ is a connected set and $\pi_X \circ \gamma$ is continuous $(\pi_X\circ \gamma)([t_0,t_1])$ is connected in $\mathbb{R}$. The only connected sets in $\mathbb{R}$ are the intervals, so then defining $I_X$ as the interval between $\sqrt{2}$ and $(\pi_X\circ \gamma)(t_1)$ we get that $I_X \subset (\pi_X\circ \gamma)([t_0,t_1])$. Likewise, there is an interval $I_Y$ such that $I_Y\subset (\pi_Y\circ \gamma)([t_0,t_1])$. I then want to argue that in these intervals there must be a point where the coordinates are either both irrational or both rational, but I don't know how to proceed and also don't feel confident in the approach.

Note that if $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ then the lines $y=x+q$ and $y=-x+q$ are disjoint from $S$. Fix any $(a,b)\in S$. We pick rational numbers $q_1,q_2,q_3,q_4$ so that
$q_1$ is slightly larger than $b-a$
$q_2$ is slightly smaller than $b-a$
$q_3$ is slightly larger than $a+b$
$q_4$ is slightly smaller than $a+b$
Then the closed square $D$ bounded by the four lines $y=x+q_1$, $y=x+q_2$, $y=-x+q_3$, $y=-x+q_4$ is an arbitrarily small neighborhood of $(a,b)$, and its boundary $\partial D$ is disjoint from $S$, so $D\cap S$ is both open and closed in $S$. This shows $S$ is zero-dimensional, and in particular not connected.

Since the question was just about connectedness, I'll add that you can just pick any "diamond" made by these lines and the regions inside and outside the diamond are disjoint open subsets covering $S$.

@MartianInvader: in order to just prove disconnectedness, it would even be sufficient just to consider the diagonal, Hence, the "upper" part is clopen in $S$.

No, $S$ is zero-dimensional:
For $q \in \mathbb Q$ let $A_q = \{q\} \times (\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q) \subset S$.
Then $cl_S (A_q) = $ the closure of $A_q$ in $S$ equals
$cl_{\mathbb R} (A_q) \cap S = (\{q\} \times \mathbb R) \cap S = A_q$.
Hence, $A_q$ is closed in $S$.
Moreover, $A_q$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$,
hence strongly zero-dimensional, i.e. $\text{dim}(A_q) = 0$.
Similarly, $B_q = (\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q) \times  \{q\}\subset S$ is closed in $S$, and $\text{dim}(B_q) = 0$.
Since $S = \bigcup_{q \in \mathbb Q} A_q \cup \bigcup_{q \in \mathbb Q} B_q$, by the countable sum theorem for dim, we have $\text{dim}(S) = 0$.
Addendum 
Your proof attempt of connectness of $S$ would show that each dense set of a connected space is connected, in particular that $\mathbb Q$ is connected.
If you just apply your arguments to
$\mathbb Q = ((-\infty, \pi) \cap \mathbb Q) \cup  ((\pi, \infty) \cap \mathbb Q)$, you will see that
$\tilde{U}\cup \tilde{V}$ need not cover the whole space, but just that it is dense.

Thank you for your answer! We haven’t covered the definition of topological dimension in the course I’m doing. Is there some way to prove that $S$ is disconnected with a more basic approach? Also, what was incorrect in my proof that $S$ is connected?

@Joseph Basford:  I added an analysis of your proof as an addendum to my answer.
About your first question:
I didn't know, that you wanted to solve this as part of an introductory topology course, where it's really unlikely that dim is covered.
Was this an exercise to this course? If yes, what was the exact formulation?
Probably, it is possible to prove disconnectedness by elementary methods, e.g. just to describe a clopen set. Later, I will think about it.

The lines $y=x+q$ and $y=-x+q$ are disjoint from $S$ for any rational $q$, which give you diamond-like clopen neighborhoods.

@183orbco3: yes, indeed! Why don't you post this as an answer?
